# Create columns in a dataframe filled with certain criteria using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this dataframe with two columns:

```
    df<-structure(c(3.39731077987836, 3.35113905626126, 3.54151558185337, 
3.32908416124226, 3.11708556895431, 2.63033674090622, 3.26358791285813, 
3.285473899684, 2.11527332084524, 1.25521701811421, 0.558756742281551, 
-0.478780166461706, -0.667471284066706, -0.814286812271371, -1.4892267510757, 
-1.95734076424983, -2.39782989530402, -2.10637673680131, -1.79945196199986, 
-0.699075436407749, -0.686257092778993, -0.397822856743792, -0.0798214490317454, 
-0.532685697966011, -0.502453448481614, 0.124038497996675, -0.183209858531146, 
-0.207727844806884, -0.42181300275947, -1.55064839647219, -0.940915675467525, 
-0.282337163324608, -0.282104913840212, 0.0517233625425734, -0.0959578223084026, 
-0.356446953362597, -0.586070427770486, -0.00389588872917584, 
-0.706760137663439, -0.499624386597704, -0.265363281891766, 0.335157519808067, 
-0.0564082441567325, -1.04811828422925, -1.25133778553553, -1.19362493003892, 
-1.51921954922526, -1.66301615496241, -1.03652420848412, -1.00636953495087, 
-1.06613728546647, -0.991731904652815, -1.46358622083305, -1.41903656391168, 
-1.1216122606305, -1.57166856336155, -1.49467708840353, -1.21322392990081, 
-0.75881854908715, -0.418730575710473, -0.0800077874598371, 0.240368738132275, 
0.0506676877732472, -0.157657301665174, -0.327569328288499, -0.305106237031753, 
-0.0708451323258146, 0.339675669374017, 0.435446235313711, 0.323159090810323, 
0.305477905959347, 0.500815643575891, 0.697451866161896, 0.504088088747904, 
0.185252695035182, 0.149946628064277, 0.098092311884041, -0.11973314907465, 
-0.0321645696857616, -0.430422858967607, 0.0560690875106806, 
0.079253559306016, 0.651283822239604, 0.302448428526886, 0.282680678011282, 
0.137663163255812, 0.0376068605247707, 0.175752544344534, 0.619292268511883, 
0.252188188091779, 0.629112962893222, 0.504017872186609, 0.236836215815368, 
-0.235883757011178, -0.341334100089804, -0.00419834902406702, 
0.0184090183403975, 0.710295005166268, 0.514988938195361, 0.470115699547611, 
0.528261383367372, 0.569070737282641, -0.0622064744667214, -0.597656817545347, 
-0.783107160623972, -0.670433093102934, -0.638114277953906, -0.705795462804879, 
-0.793188095440416, -0.502023489153139, -0.202656896315051, -0.335732121513609, 
-0.624201387059748, -0.282459676341596, -0.598342847743377, -0.705957332437773, 
-0.547667372510291, -0.703550543912073, -0.958645634618686, -0.748990489565163, 
-0.367393054954727, 0.188666063200407, 0.852927167906345, 1.13423605030134, 
1.40015089234876, 1.02844085227624, 0.964499970431373, 1.73250137814342, 
2.08424308886157, 1.74360968169966, 1.58729368197473, 1.30911296864402, 
1.04855713743325, 1.19375059894207, 1.33729032310942, 0.911695703923079, 
0.79343741464123, 0.976832862700858, 0.682248176268544, 0.479172951069985, 
0.593356479824784, 0.825741995130385, 0.201656837177799, 0.0877159553329318, 
-0.200253781733476, -0.281464293326265, -0.423751437829655, -0.849923161446871, 
-0.548758555159591, -0.775574083364255, -0.812678163784358, -0.918994163509289, 
-0.71214696465899, -0.987741583845334, -0.999307347810134, -0.264546714624464, 
-0.110574162133963, 0.445984484500902, 0.453985892212947, 0.342420128248148, 
0.344738943397175, 0.105759273576736, 0.00051990676240643, -0.440113500399508, 
-0.669592698699677, -0.851879843203069, -0.589128199730886, -0.328107869551325, 
-0.253702488737667, -0.260806569157768, -0.0286320301164601, 
0.183398232817129, 0.0670822330921953, 0.157891587007462, -0.261587611292705, 
-0.320423005005425, -0.704508162958012, -0.894420189581332, -0.835053596743246, 
-0.499715859126705, -0.482868660276407, -0.675799609367244, -0.894779279187683, 
-1.28857588492483, -1.75445905632661, -1.27811138595604, -1.26262937223178, 
-1.16361803176571, -0.725183795730507, -0.505528650676985, -0.866084481887756, 
-1.14240048161269, -0.924687626116082, -1.22309019150565, -0.949406191230579, 
-0.314712258201487, -0.191172534034138, 0.259636819881127, 0.0582153320240489, 
-0.397812115485449, -0.393406734671792, -0.201598323797064, -0.0677700474142788, 
0.584115939411592, 0.347944215794377, 0.773070977146622, 0.653014674415583, 
1.01173746266622, 0.958085133036788, 0.961624857204136, 1.12883818422102, 
1.2553301306993, 1.11045689205155, 1.1811219698591, 1.67588260304477, 
2.11136461676903, 1.56742373492416, 1.14873261731916, 1.60076288025275, 
1.30085085362943, 1.64215973602443, 0.943546194370568, 0.645076928824428, 
0.905164902201106, 1.04165684867939, 0.744552768259294, 1.02046761030671, 
0.953718782258619, 0.627979886964559, 0.420442978221301, 0.160963779921135, 
-0.263409930246887, -0.277350812091753, -0.239205128271991, -0.364511195242898, 
-0.0344232218662192, -0.376277538046457, -0.197843302011256, 
0.0770616072821318, -0.304504156682666, -0.229954499761293, -1.07821278904314, 
-0.954884041140085, -0.682276673775623, -0.435351898974179, -0.449226080662472, 
-0.17438787152566, -0.156530739921331, -1.56910643664016, -1.55823038256832, 
3.39731077987836, 3.35113905626126, 3.54151558185337, 3.32908416124226, 
3.11708556895431, 2.63033674090622, 3.26358791285813, 3.285473899684, 
2.11527332084524, 1.25521701811421, 0.558756742281551, -0.478780166461706, 
-0.667471284066706, -0.814286812271371, -1.4892267510757, -1.95734076424983, 
-2.39782989530402, -2.10637673680131, -1.79945196199986, -0.699075436407749, 
-0.686257092778993, -0.397822856743792, -0.0798214490317454, 
-0.532685697966011, -0.502453448481614, 0.124038497996675, -0.183209858531146, 
-0.207727844806884, -0.42181300275947, -1.55064839647219, -0.940915675467525, 
-0.282337163324608, -0.282104913840212, 0.0517233625425734, -0.0959578223084026, 
-0.356446953362597, -0.586070427770486, -0.00389588872917584, 
-0.706760137663439, -0.499624386597704, -0.265363281891766, 0.335157519808067, 
-0.0564082441567325, -1.04811828422925, -1.25133778553553, -1.19362493003892, 
-1.51921954922526, -1.66301615496241, -1.03652420848412, -1.00636953495087, 
-1.06613728546647, -0.991731904652815, -1.46358622083305, -1.41903656391168, 
-1.1216122606305, -1.57166856336155, -1.49467708840353, -1.21322392990081, 
-0.75881854908715, -0.418730575710473, -0.0800077874598371, 0.240368738132275, 
0.0506676877732472, -0.157657301665174, -0.327569328288499, -0.305106237031753, 
-0.0708451323258146, 0.339675669374017, 0.435446235313711, 0.323159090810323, 
0.305477905959347, 0.500815643575891, 0.697451866161896, 0.504088088747904, 
0.185252695035182, 0.149946628064277, 0.098092311884041, -0.11973314907465, 
-0.0321645696857616, -0.430422858967607, 0.0560690875106806, 
0.079253559306016, 0.651283822239604, 0.302448428526886, 0.282680678011282, 
0.137663163255812, 0.0376068605247707, 0.175752544344534, 0.619292268511883, 
0.252188188091779, 0.629112962893222, 0.504017872186609, 0.236836215815368, 
-0.235883757011178, -0.341334100089804, -0.00419834902406702, 
0.0184090183403975, 0.710295005166268, 0.514988938195361, 0.470115699547611, 
0.528261383367372, 0.569070737282641, -0.0622064744667214, -0.597656817545347, 
-0.783107160623972, -0.670433093102934, -0.638114277953906, -0.705795462804879, 
-0.793188095440416, -0.502023489153139, -0.202656896315051, -0.335732121513609, 
-0.624201387059748, -0.282459676341596, -0.598342847743377, -0.705957332437773, 
-0.547667372510291, -0.703550543912073, -0.958645634618686, -0.748990489565163, 
-0.367393054954727, 0.188666063200407, 0.852927167906345, 1.13423605030134, 
1.40015089234876, 1.02844085227624, 0.964499970431373, 1.73250137814342, 
2.08424308886157, 1.74360968169966, 1.58729368197473, 1.30911296864402, 
1.04855713743325, 1.19375059894207, 1.33729032310942, 0.911695703923079, 
0.79343741464123, 0.976832862700858, 0.682248176268544, 0.479172951069985, 
0.593356479824784, 0.825741995130385, 0.201656837177799, 0.0877159553329318, 
-0.200253781733476, -0.281464293326265, -0.423751437829655, -0.849923161446871, 
-0.548758555159591, -0.775574083364255, -0.812678163784358, -0.918994163509289, 
-0.71214696465899, -0.987741583845334, -0.999307347810134, -0.264546714624464, 
-0.110574162133963, 0.445984484500902, 0.453985892212947, 0.342420128248148, 
0.344738943397175, 0.105759273576736, 0.00051990676240643, -0.440113500399508, 
-0.669592698699677, -0.851879843203069, -0.589128199730886, -0.328107869551325, 
-0.253702488737667, -0.260806569157768, -0.0286320301164601, 
0.183398232817129, 0.0670822330921953, 0.157891587007462, -0.261587611292705, 
-0.320423005005425, -0.704508162958012, -0.894420189581332, -0.835053596743246, 
-0.499715859126705, -0.482868660276407, -0.675799609367244, -0.894779279187683, 
-1.28857588492483, -1.75445905632661, -1.27811138595604, -1.26262937223178, 
-1.16361803176571, -0.725183795730507, -0.505528650676985, -0.866084481887756, 
-1.14240048161269, -0.924687626116082, -1.22309019150565, -0.949406191230579, 
-0.314712258201487, -0.191172534034138, 0.259636819881127, 0.0582153320240489, 
-0.397812115485449, -0.393406734671792, -0.201598323797064, -0.0677700474142788, 
0.584115939411592, 0.347944215794377, 0.773070977146622, 0.653014674415583, 
1.01173746266622, 0.958085133036788, 0.961624857204136, 1.12883818422102, 
1.2553301306993, 1.11045689205155, 1.1811219698591, 1.67588260304477, 
2.11136461676903, 1.56742373492416, 1.14873261731916, 1.60076288025275, 
1.30085085362943, 1.64215973602443, 0.943546194370568, 0.645076928824428, 
0.905164902201106, 1.04165684867939, 0.744552768259294, 1.02046761030671, 
0.953718782258619, 0.627979886964559, 0.420442978221301, 0.160963779921135, 
-0.263409930246887, -0.277350812091753, -0.239205128271991, -0.364511195242898, 
-0.0344232218662192, -0.376277538046457, -0.197843302011256, 
0.0770616072821318, -0.304504156682666, -0.229954499761293, -1.07821278904314, 
-0.954884041140085, -0.682276673775623, -0.435351898974179, -0.449226080662472, 
-0.17438787152566, -0.156530739921331, -1.56910643664016, -1.55823038256832
), .Dim = c(250L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("columnA", "columnB"
)))
```

I need to create columns next to columnA and columnB  filled with 0, 1, -1, or -2.

The column next to columnA receives the value 0 when its value is between 1.016414 and - 1.016414, it will receive the value of 1 when its value is between 1.016414 and 2 * 1.016414. It will receive the value 2 when it is above 2 * 1.016414. It will receive -2 value if it is below -2 * 1.016414. It will recevive the -1 value if its value is between -1*1.016414 and 2 * - 1.016414.

This, then, would be the column next to the column columnA.

To create the column next to the columnB I will use the same criteria.

In the end I will have a dataframe with 4 columns.

Is it possible to do this with dplyr package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by cutting the vector by pre-specified cutoffs. Since you want this repeated, you can wrap it in a function.

```
customClassification <- function(x) {
  out <- cut(x, breaks = c(-Inf, 2 * -1.016414, -1.016414, 1.016414, 2 * 1.016414, Inf),
             labels = c(-2, 1, 0, 1, 2))
  as.numeric(as.character(out))
}


xy <- cbind(test, classA = customClassification(test[, "columnA"]))
head(xy, 20)

         columnA    columnB classA
 [1,]  3.3973108  3.3973108      2
 [2,]  3.3511391  3.3511391      2
 [3,]  3.5415156  3.5415156      2
 [4,]  3.3290842  3.3290842      2
 [5,]  3.1170856  3.1170856      2
 [6,]  2.6303367  2.6303367      2
 [7,]  3.2635879  3.2635879      2
 [8,]  3.2854739  3.2854739      2
 [9,]  2.1152733  2.1152733      2
[10,]  1.2552170  1.2552170      1
[11,]  0.5587567  0.5587567      0
[12,] -0.4787802 -0.4787802      0
[13,] -0.6674713 -0.6674713      0
[14,] -0.8142868 -0.8142868      0
[15,] -1.4892268 -1.4892268      1
[16,] -1.9573408 -1.9573408      1
[17,] -2.3978299 -2.3978299     -2
[18,] -2.1063767 -2.1063767     -2
[19,] -1.7994520 -1.7994520      1
[20,] -0.6990754 -0.6990754      0
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative option using `case_when`:

```
library(dplyr)

data.frame(df) %>%
  mutate_all(funs(new = case_when(between(., -1.016414, 1.016414) ~ 0,
                                  between(., 1.016414, 2*1.016414) ~ 1,
                                  . > 2*1.016414 ~ 2,
                                  . < -2*1.016414 ~ -2,
                                  TRUE ~ -1))) %>%
  tbl_df()   # only for visualisation purposes

# # A tibble: 250 x 4
#      columnA columnB columnA_new columnB_new
#      <dbl>   <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
# 1    3.40    3.40           2           2
# 2    3.35    3.35           2           2
# 3    3.54    3.54           2           2
# 4    3.33    3.33           2           2
# 5    3.12    3.12           2           2
# 6    2.63    2.63           2           2
# 7    3.26    3.26           2           2
# 8    3.29    3.29           2           2
# 9    2.12    2.12           2           2
#10    1.26    1.26           1           1
# # ... with 240 more rows
```

Note that `case_when` works sequentially and `between` works as `x >= left & x <= right`, so if you ever have a value like `1.016414` it will first return value `0` and then this will be updated to `1` (i.e. after the 1st and 2nd `between`). Therefore the process will return `1` for that value.

Comment: @AntonioK Thanks! I would like to have `columnA_new` next to columnA. How can I do?

Comment: There are various ways to re-arrange column order. One of them is by adding `... %>% select(matches("A"), everything())` in the end of the script.

Answer (score 0):

here is what you need:

```
  CompFun<-function(x){
   if(x > -1.016414 & x < 1.016414){return(0)}
   if(x < 2*1.016414 & x > 1.016414){return(1)}
   if(x > 2*-1.016414 & x < -1.016414){return(-1)}
   if(x > 2*1.016414){return(2)}
   if(x < 2*-1.016414){return(-2)}
  }
df<-as.data.frame(df)
library("dplyr")
res<-df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
   mutate(ColAA= CompFun(columnA),colBB=CompFun(columnB))
head(res)
   #  columnA columnB ColAA colBB
   #    <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
   #1    3.40    3.40    2.    2.
   #2    3.35    3.35    2.    2.
   #3    3.54    3.54    2.    2.
   #4    3.33    3.33    2.    2.
   #5    3.12    3.12    2.    2.
   #6    2.63    2.63    2.    2.
```